# Footer background isnt showing on iphone

Tags: iphone, css, wordpress, background, footer

I've got a footer background on this site www.vostip.mk
This is the code

```
div#omc-inner-footer {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 950px;
 padding: 40px 40px 0px 40px;
 background: url("http://vostip.mk/wp/wp-content/uploads/footerbg.jpg") no-repeat;  
}
```

The background is showing up on PC but not on iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have added the above styles to the style_1024.css file which is only applied to PC version of the site(not the iphone version)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) { ... }
```

For iPhone, you need to add the background styles to the respective stylesheet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, good spot, I might have been overthinking it with my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at your vostip.mk site, and it looks like the elements within your div are all floated, and you're relying on a `<br>` with `clear:both`; to push down the containing div so you can see the background on it.  This'll work on desktop, but perhaps this is the problem on iphone, especially as it's naturally an inline element, it may not be clearing your child elements.  Try explicitly setting a height of the containing div to see if this fixes it.

Also something at the back of my mind is telling me I've had iphone issues with backgrounds on elements before when they don't have a position property explicitly set - try adding a `position: relative;` to the containing div too.

Failing that, try debugging using something like this: http://debug.phonegap.com/